# how to prove that a function is not complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, analyticity

I was working on a problem on the complex differentiability of the following function:

$f(z)= z \operatorname{Re}(z)$. How to find the points where the given function is not differentiable. My effort:

$f(z)= z\operatorname{Re}(z) = zx$ where $x$ is the real part of $z$. No after applying the differentition 
formula i got
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{f(z+\Delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z}
&=&\frac{(z+\Delta z)Re(z+\Delta z)-zx}{\Delta z}
&=&\frac{(z+\Delta z)(x+\Delta x)-zx}{\Delta z}
\end{eqnarray*}

with the limit $\Delta z$ tends to $0$. Now how do I find the points where function is not differentiable? Kindly help. Any suggestion or hint will be helpful.

Comment: Note that $f(z+\Delta z)=(z+\Delta z)x+(z+\Delta z)\Re(\Delta z).$

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy Riemann equations? Or some other criterion for complex differentiability.

Comment: yeah I know C-R equations.... but I am trying to prove without using C-R equations. Is it possible?

Comment: @mfl yeah you are right.... silly mistake

Comment: The term in which you see $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta z}$ must be zero because you can make this factor have length 0 or 1 by taking limits in different directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue on from where you stopped:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{f(z+\Delta z) - f(z)}{\Delta z}
&=&\frac{(z+\Delta z)Re(z+\Delta z)-zx}{\Delta z}\\
&=&\frac{(z+\Delta z)(x+\Delta x)-zx}{\Delta z}\\
&=&x+\Delta x+\frac{z\Delta x}{\Delta z}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

If $z\ne 0$, then limit $\Delta z\to 0$ along the real line gives $x+z$ but the same along with imaginary line gives $x$, and they are not equal.
If $z=0$, then it is obvious that the limit is $x$.

Comment: means it is not differentiable anywhere? only at $0$

Comment: Yes. You mean to say you didn't try the CR equations either?

Comment: actually i started from the basics...topic wise.... so 1st this topic came. and its easy to prove using CR equations... I wanted to know this method. thanks